# JSP Scriptlet: Can you insert it anywhere inside a html page and is it called before jquery document ready?

Tags: jquery, jsp

A beginner's question on JSP. let's say I have some java statement

```
<% ..... %>
```

and I have a html page"

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<script>...</script>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

can I put this java statment before `<html>` tag? after `</html>` tag? before `<body>` tag? after `</body>` tag?

If I also have a jquery document ready statement

`$(document).ready(function() {alert("ok"); });`

inside the `<script>...</script>` tag, who get executed first? my java code or alert?

Comment: For the last question: where does Java run? Where does JavaScript run? IMO it's really important to understand the fundamentals--it will save you a ton of time in the long run.

Comment: Java/JSP produces HTML/JS/CSS. Surely it runs before HTML/JS/CSS. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to get enlightenend.

Comment: Again, it's the other way round. You don't insert JSP in HTML, but you insert HTML in JSP. Rightclick page in webbrowser and do *View Source*. You'll see that it contains no single line of Java/JSP code, because it has already done its job of running in webserver and producing HTML code. Even more, webbrowsers does not understand Java/JSP at all (let alone PHP, ASP, Python, Ruby or whatever server side language). It only understands HTML (and also CSS and JS as they are as being part of HTML also client side languages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put Java JSP tags in anywhere of page, JSP gets executed before javascript

Answer (score 0):

JSP is servlet. That's server-side component. JSP is just high-level abstraction of servlets. Your JSP is translated into servlet at runtime. And this servlet will generate on server html page will sent to client and will be executed in his browser. Therefore, of course, Java code from your JSP will executed first.